# How to correctly access items in a nested R list?

Tags: r, list, syntax

In my current explorations of R, I noted that if you start with the following list object:

```
l1 = c(1,2,3,4)
```

You can then access the 3rd item in `l1` using the syntax:

```
l1[3] #-> 2
```

Meaning, to access list items by index, one can following the pattern

> **nameoflist**[index_of_item]

However, if I try this with nested lists, say the following example...

```
l2 = list("a","b", c(1,2,3,4))
```

I notice that I can correctly access the items in the top level list using the syntax before. For example:

```
l2[1] #-> "a"
l2[2] #-> "b"
l2[3] #-> 1 2 3 4
```

But check what happens when I wish to access the 2nd item of the nested list (which is itself the 3rd item in the top level list as u see in the above example)

```
l2[3][2] #-> NULL
```

But I expected to see `2` as the output of the above expression! Moreover, using the same above approach, but with index "1", returns the full list! And this happens for any extra `[1]`s you append to the expression! See the example below...

```
l2[3][1] #-> 1 2 3 4 
l2[3][1][1] #-> 1 2 3 4 
l2[3][1][1][1] #-> 1 2 3 4
```

Weird!

So, what's happening here? I haven't yet seen R docs on how to access items in nested lists, so need some assistance here.

**Update**

I have noted that there's an explanation for how to use `[[]]` for such situations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el), However, this scenario like mine might help others who don't even know about that operator yet. So, I doubt this question is exactly the same as the one linked to. That said, I've found 2 alternative ways to solve this...

Comment: `l2[[3]][2]` ...

Comment: @jogo thanks. Also found that using the more intuitive approach `l2[3][[1]][2]`  is more readable (for us coming to R from say Python)

Comment: As part of understanding the difference between [ ] and [[ ]], you should also learn the difference between lists and atomic vectors.  In R, the first object that you call a 'list', is not a list:   is.list(c(1,2,3,4)) returns FALSE.  c(1,2,3,4) is a vector, but not a list.

Comment: Alright @Joe ;-)